# How to Render an Angular Component to HTML in Node.Js (To Send EMails)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-universal

Let's say I have a simple Angular Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-content',
  template: '<h1>Welcome {{username}}!</h1>'
})
export class WelcomeEmailComponent {
  @Input() username: string
}
```

**My goal is to take this Angular component and render it to plain HTML with Node.Js, to send customized EMails.**

I know that Server-side rendering is definitely possible with [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal). But I am not sure how to explicitly render one specific component.

Comment: Can you post any examples you tried already? Also please provide your Angular version

Comment: refer the edited answer with little improvements.

Comment: @Googlian Awesome! I will look into it in the next couple days :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach is to send an Angular component-based dynamically generated templates to users' email from the Angular SSR project.

Find the example repository at the bottom of this answer.

The steps you need to follow;

1. Design your templates in an individual routing path that is dedicated to showing only the email templates not your navigation bars, global CSS, etc.

Example:

**welcome-email-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome-email-component',
  templateUrl: './welcome-email-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome-email-component.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeEmailComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  username: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.username = params.username;
    });
  }

}
```

**welcome-email-component.component.html**

```
<style>
    .title-p {
        color: #00025a;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<p class="title-p">Welcome {{username}}</p>
```

> You need to specify a route for this component as below, so when the user navigates to the `welcome-email/username` route it should show only the email template generated component.

```
{ path: 'welcome-email/:username', component: WelcomeEmailComponentComponent }
```

2. Implement Angular SSR to your project from the great Angular SSR guidelines, [Server-side rendering (SSR) with Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

It's just two lines of code.

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
npm run dev:ssr
```

3. Finally create a server-side API to generate the template from your Angular component and send emails or provide the HTML code of the single component, add the API function in your `server.ts` as below.

**server.ts**

```
server.get('/api/send-email/:username', (req, res) => {
    // Below is the URL route for the Angular welcome mail component
    request(`http://127.0.0.1:4200/welcome-email/${req.params.username}`, (error, response, body) => {
        // TODO : Send email to the user from WelcomeEmailComponentComponent.ts component as `body`
        // use the body to send email
        res.send('Email sent');
    });
});
```

Example code: https://github.com/aslamanver/angular-send-component-email

The demonstration of a dynamically generated component on this repository;

[image]

Finally when you access `/api/send-email/:username`, this will generate the welcome mail component and give the HTML body of that, thereafter you can proceed with your email sending function.

Comment: How to remove the script-src tags?

Comment: From the server-side validations before sending the email you can customize the tags as per your requirements using Node.js.

Comment: @Googlian That's a really clever approach. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Flo You are most welcome, thanks for the appreciation

Answer (score 2):

I clap @Googlian's answer. But, angular produces too much unfamiliar HTML5, CSS3 and angular specific bundled features, so after that you have to remove those one by one specifically if you want a real valid email content, otherwise your email most probably will be considered as spam bu mailclients.

I sugges that you mah have a component with xHTML standarts with no-CSS3, no-experimental HTML5 features, and build an email templete with `this` and `ElementRef`, then parse required fields manually.

Send the string to serverside, nodejs, then send it as email. You can use nodemailer

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer, the unnecessary CSS and JS imports can be removed from server-side validations.